# returning **unique** counts from each row json data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on this for a while and can't quite seem to get around it: I have a block of JSON data that looks like this

```
0    [{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}, {'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}
1    [{'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'},{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}
2    [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'},{'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'}
3    [{'code': '7', 'name': 'Social dev/gender/inclusion'}]
```

I'm trying to generate a count of each value, something like this at the end:

```
Human development : 2
Economic management : 2
Trade and integration : 1
Social dev/gender/inclusion : 1
```

**Note: there are some rows that are coded twice (like the first one) that should be counted only once**

I've tried many different things and the closest I've been is this

```
for i in range(0,len(wbp['code'])):
# create a counter for the next step, counting the number of values of each subdict
number = len(wbp['code'][i])-1

#create empty values
dictd = dict()
lis = [] 

#iterate across the sublist 
for j in range (0,number):
    temp_list=[]
    temp_list.append(wbp['code'][i][int(j)]['name'])
    #using set to return only unique values
    lis = tuple(set(temp_list))
    if lis in dictd.keys():
        dictd[lis]+=1
    else:
        dictd[lis]=1
    #lis.append(temp_list)
    #value=[[x,lis.count(x)] for x in lis]
print(dictd)
```

which returns:

```
{('Human development',): 1}
{('Economic management',): 1}
{('Trade and integration',): 1, ('Public sector governance',): 1, ('Environment and natural resources management',): 1}
{('Social dev/gender/inclusion',): 1}
{('Trade and integration',): 1}
{('Social protection and risk management',): 1}
{('Public sector governance',): 1}
{('Environment and natural resources management',): 1}
{('Rural development',): 1}
{('Public sector governance',): 2}
{('Rural development',): 1}
{('Rural development',): 1, ('Social protection and risk management',): 2}
{}
{('Trade and integration',): 1, ('Environment and natural resources management',): 1}
{('Social protection and risk management',): 2}
{('Rural development',): 1, ('Environment and natural resources management',): 1}
{('Rural development',): 1}
{('Human development',): 1}
```

That's not right in that it isn't a working counter outside of the internal dicts which isn't what I want anyway. All I can think is there must be a wildly more pythonic way to do this...

**EDIT:** seems I've done poorly at clarity: again there are errors in the data set, in that there are entries like row 0 that have duplicates. **those should not be counted twice**. the expected return for Human development should be 2, not three, because that first row is an error.

Comment: I don't understand your example. Give me an input and an expected output

Comment: Should the count for code `'Human development'` be 3?

Comment: Does your input json looks like this?
`{
        [{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}, {'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}],
        [{'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'},{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}],
        [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'},{'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'}],
        [{'code': '7', 'name': 'Social dev/gender/inclusion'}]
    }`

Comment: @SwadhikarC, no, the count should be 2, because the first version is an error. no entry should be able to count for a value twice. yes, that's what the input looks like (a substring of it anyway)

Comment: @ChienNguyen input is first box, expected output is second

Comment: @SwadhikarC; I think you posted ( and maybe deleted?) something that worked.I can re post it but I'd like to give you credit, so if you wanted to put it back up...

Comment: Ike glad that it worked that's the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input details are unclear, I have assumed that your input as below and have come with below code:

```
    wbp = [[{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}, {'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}],
       [{'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'}, {'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}],
       [{'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'}, {'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'}],
       [{'code': '7', 'name': 'Social dev/gender/inclusion'}]]

dictd = dict()

    for record in wbp:
        names = set([item['name'] for item in record]) # Remove duplicate names using set
        for name in names:
            dictd[name] = dictd.get(name, 0) + 1  # If name not found, then 0 + 1, else count + 1

    print(dictd)
```

Which results in

> {
>
> 'Economic management': 2,
>
> 'Social dev/gender/inclusion': 1,
>
> 'Human development': 2,
>
> 'Trade and integration': 1
>
> }

Comment: yes on the data structure, the problem is human development should be 2, since that first row is an error (there can only be one of each item per row)

Comment: Ok, i've modified the input and filtered duplicate entries using `set` operator. Now the results are as how you expected

Comment: this seems to have reappeared some how, it worked a charm then.

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand the second for loop the `temp_list` is created at every iteration as empty list, then why do you need to do this `lis = tuple(set(temp_list))`
 instead read it in a variable `name` :

```
name = wbp['code'][i][int(j)]['name']

if name in dictd.keys():
    dictd[name]+=1
else:
    dictd[name]=1
```

Comment: the problem is the duplicate errors, which is what I'm trying to account for there; see the first row should really be just [{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}] instead of [[{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'},[{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'},] but since that's there I have to make a unique set of each row. although there could certainly be an easier way around that?

Comment: see comment above, that's close but misses the dupes

Answer (score 0):

```
input = [{'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'},
        {'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'},
        {'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'},
        {'code': '8', 'name': 'Human development'}, 
        {'code': '5', 'name': 'Trade and integration'},
        {'code': '1', 'name': 'Economic management'},
        {'code': '7', 'name': 'Social dev/gender/inclusion'}]
output = {}
for i in input:
    output[i['name']] = output.get(i['name'], 0) + 1
#Output:{'Social dev/gender/inclusion': 1, 'Economic management': 2, 'Human 
#        development': 3, 'Trade and integration': 1}
```

Comment: problem again is the duplicates that are false, as in row one.